# Getting the coordinates from touchscreen

Tags: stm32

I have a some problem at the my touchscreen. I am using FT6236 touch screen driver for the TFTM032 touch screen. I get the touch information from the i2c protocol but i dont know how can i determine the coordinates. I am using stm32f3 discover board and programming with the standard perhipral library. I try the this code but it doesnt work

```
if (touch_event.event_id == 0)
  {


    if (buf.gest_id & TOUCH_FT6236_GESTURE_MOVE_FLAG)
    {

      // gesture for us! -> overwrite clicks
      touch_event.event_id = (buf.gest_id & 0x0F) + 1;
      touch_event.x = 0;
      touch_event.y = 0;
    }

    else
    {

      uint8_t ev = buf.points[0].event >> 6;
  touch_event.event_id = TOUCH_GESTURE_MOUSE_DOWN + ev;
      touch_event.y = (buf.points[0].xhi & 0x0F) << 8 | (buf.points[0].xlo);
      touch_event.y = (touch_event.y >> 1);
      touch_event.x = (buf.points[0].yhi & 0x0F) << 8 | (buf.points[0].ylo);
      touch_event.x = 128 - (touch_event.x >> 1);
    }
    xpos = touch_event.x;
    ypos = touch_event.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/cnoviello/stm32-discof7/blob/master/stm32-discof7-lcddim/system/src/BSP/stm32746g_discovery_ts.c#L219) can be helpful, check the method `BSP_TS_GetState`

Comment: thank you but its little different from my codes

Comment: yeah sorry! just thought It could be something related :) Are you using any kind of online documentation for this?